# AWS Cognito doesn't call confirmSignUp when confirming user identity in Swift with Xcode

Tags: swift, amazon-web-services, amazon-cognito

I finally managed to get the SignUp to work, but when trying to confirm the signup, I'm reaching a problem. Here is my code:

```
var user: AWSCognitoIdentityUser?

@IBAction func submitButton(_ sender: Any) {
    guard let confirmationCodeValue = self.codeTextField.text, !confirmationCodeValue.isEmpty else {
        let confirmationAlert = UIAlertController(title: alertTitle, message: alertMessage, preferredStyle: .alert)
        confirmationAlert.addAction(UIAlertAction(title: "好", style: .default, handler: {action in
            print("Try again!")
        }))
        self.present(confirmationAlert, animated: true, completion: nil)

        return
    }

    self.user?.confirmSignUp(self.codeTextField.text!, forceAliasCreation: true).continue({[weak self] (task: AWSTask) -> Any? in
        guard let strongSelf = self else { return nil }
        DispatchQueue.main.async(execute: {
            print("At least this is working...")
            if let error = task.error {
                let confirmationFailAlert = UIAlertController(title: (error as NSError).userInfo["__type"] as? String,
                                                              message: (error as NSError).userInfo["__type"] as? String,
                                                              preferredStyle: .alert)
                confirmationFailAlert.addAction(UIAlertAction(title: "好",
                                                              style: .default,
                                                              handler: {action in
                }))
                self?.present(confirmationFailAlert, animated: true, completion: nil)
            } else {
                let confirmationSuccessAlert = UIAlertController(title: self?.alertTitleConfirmationComplete,
                                                                 message:self?.alertMessageConfirmationComplete,
                                                                 preferredStyle: .alert)
                confirmationSuccessAlert.addAction(UIAlertAction(title: "好",
                                                                 style: .default,
                                                                 handler: {action in
                                                                    self?.dismiss(animated: true, completion: nil)
                }))
                self?.present(confirmationSuccessAlert, animated: true, completion: nil)
            }
        })
        return nil
    })

}
```

The first part of this code works fine. If I type nothing in the space, I get an alertView telling me so. However, if I type anything in the space, nothing happens. The print statement "At least this is working..." never gets called. I've been staring at this code for a couple hours now trying to figure out what's wrong, and I feel like it's probably something simple, but as of now, I could use some help!

Thanks in advance!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I assume the code block above is not the full source, but be sure the **optional**, `user`, is "unencapsulated" and equal to an actual instance of `AWSCognitoIdentityUser`.

If it isn't, which I am assuming it is not, `confirmSignUp` won't know the `username`, `sub`, or have any information on the user it is "confirming".

I would recommend logging `user` and be sure that `username` is in fact a value within `user`.

I believe you set it equal to that instance type in the response to your [AWSCognitoIdentityUserPool](http://docs.aws.amazon.com/AWSiOSSDK/latest/Classes/AWSCognitoIdentityUserPool.html#//api/name/signUp:password:userAttributes:validationData:) class `signUp:password:userAttributes:validationData:` call.

Check those values that are returned in `AWSCognitoIdentityUserPoolSignUpResponse`.

Comment: You were absolutely correct. It seems so simple and I feel stupid. Not sure how I couldn't figure that out for so long. Thank you!

Comment: Absolutely! And not a problem at all. These little things are the "programmers bane!"